# How Do I Create a WordPress Demo Site with Limited Admin Access

Tags: theme-development, theme-customizer

So I have developed a WordPress theme. Now I would like to setup a demo site for users to take the theme for a test run without having to install it on their end. It would have one demo account. With the demo account you will be able to access the WordPress admin dashboard, and test the theme customizer. However the account will not be able to save any posts/pages or customizer settings. Maybe an error message that says settings/posts cannot be saved. Is there a way to achieve this? Maybe a plugin available that can enable me to do this? Just have no idea how to go about doing this and would love any help that can be provided. Thanks

Comment: Use the plugin `user_role_editor` and create custom role with capabilities that you want to allow.

Answer (score 0):

I would think that you would need to give the user the ability to create posts/pages and save customizer settings to really get a feel of the theme.

I would create a new "admin" user role that has all the permissions of an admin, except creating/deleting users. This way you can't get locked out of your site. Then i would create a function by hooking into the [`wp_logout` action hook](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_logout) to delete all posts/pages, and set the customizer settings back to default, when the user logs out.

Alternatively, you can use the [Adminimize](https://wordpress.org/plugins/adminimize/) plugin, which should enable you to do exactly what you want.